# Retirar pontuação de um ficheiro Python

Tags: python, regex

Tenho este código:

```
dataClean = ''.join(data).lower()
dataClean = re.sub(r'["-,.:@#?!&$]', ' ', dataClean)
print(dataClean)
```

Onde `data` é um vetor de um ficheiro de texto. O meu objetivo é retirar a pontuação, como sinais de exclamação, vírgulas, e os demais. O código acima compila mas não está a tirar nem aspas nem travessões. Alguém sabe porquê?

---

E para o caso das palavras com travessão, como "disse-lhe"? Há alguma exceção para que não seja tirado este hífen?

Comment: Você sabe o que o código faz? Sua RegExp não foi escrita pra remover aspas simples nem travessões.

Comment: @walt057, quais são todos os sinais de pontuação que você está tentando remover?
Detalhe todos para que possa ver o que você fez e ajudar com a resposta. 
Também sugiro dar uma olhada mais a fundo em Regex, pois o que você escreveu não me parece nem perto do que você quer alcançar com o código

Comment: @fernandosavio Na verdade esta regex remove o apóstrofo (que seria a aspas simples?). Meio que "sem querer", é verdade, mas remove :-) - Eu detalho isso na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348482/112052) abaixo...

Comment: @hkotsubo Cara, tô cego. Não tô achando aspas simples (ou apóstrofo) na regex. hahaha. Esquece, li sua resposta agora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro de colchetes, o hífen tem significado especial: ele serve para definir [intervalos de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), como por exemplo `[a-z]`, que significa "uma letra de `a` a `z` (minúscula)".

O detalhe é que estes intervalos não se limitam a letras, você pode colocar quaisquer caracteres que quiser. No seu caso, `"-,` dentro dos colchetes é interpretado como "qualquer caractere entre `"` e `,`", usando como base os *code points* do Unicode (que no caso destes caracteres, são os mesmos valores da [tabela ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/)).

Ou seja, `["-,]` vai pegar qualquer caractere desta lista: `"`, `#`, `$`, `%`, `&`, `'`, `(`, `)`, `*`, `+` e `,`, olha só:

```
# encontrar os caracteres da string que correspondem à regex ["-,]
for m in re.finditer('["-,]', 'abc"#$%&*+,()\'def'):
    print(m.group(), end=" ")
```

A saída deste código é:

> " # $ % & * + , ( ) '

Ou seja, a expressão que você está usando já substitui estes caracteres, além dos outros que você colocou em seguida: `.`, `:`, `@`, `#`, `?`, `!`, `&` e `$` (sim, alguns são redundantes, pois já estão contemplados pelo intervalo `"-,`).

---

De qualquer forma, para que o hífen não signifique "intervalo entre o que vem antes e o que vem depois dele" e seja interpretado como o próprio hífen, basta escapá-lo com `\`. Ou seja, basta colocar `\-` em vez de simplesmente `-`.

Mas já que estamos usando intervalos, por que não aproveitar e usar um que já pegue os caracteres que você quer? Você poderia, por exemplo, usar `[!-.:-@]`, que contém 2 intervalos:

- `!-.` pega todos os caracteres entre `!` e `.`
- `:-@` pega todos entre `:` e `@`

Isso já inclui o hífen, as aspas duplas e simples (`"` e `'`) e todos os outros que você tinha colocado na sua expressão original. Veja novamente a [tabela ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) para saber todos os caracteres que são considerados.

O segundo intervalo pega alguns caracteres a mais que você não havia colocado anteriormente (como o `=` e `>`). Se quer que eles não sejam substituídos, basta retirar os intervalos e colocar os caracteres que você quer, um a um. Por exemplo, para adicionar o hífen e as aspas simples na sua regex original, faça `["\'\-,.:@#?!&$]`.

Enfim, independente do que você escolher, agora a regex remove o hífen e as aspas:

```
s = 'a"-b\':!?@#.c'
print('antes ', s)
s = re.sub('[!-.:-@]', ' ', s)
print('depois', s)
```

Saída:

```
antes  a"-b':!?@#.c
depois a  b       c
```

---

No código acima, você está substituindo os caracteres por um espaço. Se quiser remover os caracteres, basta fazer a substituição por `''` (sem o espaço entre as aspas):

```
s = re.sub('[!-.:-@]', '', s)
```

Assim, o resultado passa a ser `abc` (sem os espaços).

---

#### Não substituir o hífen entre palavras

Neste caso eu quebraria em 2 etapas: primeiro eu removo os hífens que não estão entre palavras, e depois eu removo os demais caracteres.

Para a primeira etapa, eu só quero substituir o hífen caso ele preencha pelo menos um dos dois requisitos abaixo:

- não tem uma letra antes, **ou**
- não tem uma letra depois

Se nenhum desses critérios for cumprido, quer dizer que ele não deve ser removido. Para isso vou usar [*lookaheads* e *lookbehinds* negativos](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), que são formas de fazer a regex "olhar o que tem antes e depois". A expressão fica assim:

```
s = re.sub(r'(?<![a-z])-|-(?![a-z])', '', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Estou usando `[a-z]` para detectar qualquer letra de `a` a `z`. Então eu verifico 2 condições:

- `(?<![a-z])-`: hífen que não possui uma letra antes (a sintaxe `(?<!...)` verifica se algo não está antes da posição atual), **ou**
- `-(?![a-z])`: hífen que não possui uma letra depois (a sintaxe `(?!...)` verifica se algo não está depois da posição atual)

Também uso a opção [`IGNORECASE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE) para que a regex considere também letras maiúsculas. Com isso, os hífens que possuem uma letra antes e depois não serão substituídos.

Se quiser incluir caracteres acentuados, pode usar por exemplo `[a-záéíóúâêôãõç]` em vez de `[a-z]` (inclua mais caracteres nos colchetes, se precisar). Outra opção é usar `\w`, mas o problema é que `\w` também aceita números e o caractere `_` (portanto, você decide se é uma boa opção ou não). Outro detalhe é que no [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html) o `\w` só pega caracteres acentuados se a opção [`UNICODE`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) for habilitada, enquanto [no Python 3 ele já pega acentos por padrão](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-31). Enfim, escolha o que encaixar melhor nos seus casos de uso.

Em seguida, eu faço a substituição do mesmo jeito que havia feito anteriormente, mas excluindo o hífen (pois os que tinham que ser substituídos já foram). O código então ficaria assim:

```
s = 'a"-b\':!?@#.c disse-lhe amá-la'
print('antes ', s)
# substituir hífens, desde que não estejam entre palavras
s = re.sub(r'(?<![a-záéíóúâêôãõç])-|-(?![a-záéíóúâêôãõç])', '', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
# substituir os caracteres especiais, exceto o hífen
s = re.sub('[!-,.:-@]', '', s)
print('depois', s)
```

A saída é:

```
antes  a"-b':!?@#.c disse-lhe amá-la
depois abc disse-lhe amá-la
```

Repare que somente o primeiro hífen foi substituído, pois ele não estava entre duas letras (apesar de ter um `b` depois, antes tinha um `"`). E agora o conteúdo dos colchetes mudou para `[!-,.:-@]`, para não considerar o hífen (agora é o intervalo `!-,`, o ponto (`.`) e o intervalo `:-@`).

Claro que, se quiser, pode colocar tudo em uma única regex:

```
s = re.sub(r'[!-,.:-@]|(?<![a-záéíóúâêôãõç])-|-(?![a-záéíóúâêôãõç])', '', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Eu já acho que começa ficar complicado para entender e principalmente manter futuramente. Mas novamente, você decide qual opção usar.

---

### Aspas

A sua primeira versão da regex já deveria remover as aspas. Se não está removendo, desconfio que suas strings não tem exatamente o caractere `"`.

Isso acontece porque `"` não é o único caractere de aspas que existe. Nas categorias Unicode ["Punctuation, Open"](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Ps/list.htm) e ["Punctuation, Close"](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pe/list.htm) existem vários outros caracteres de aspas, como por exemplo o `〝` e o `〞`, além de outras "aspas" não tão "óbvias", como o `《` e o `｢`.

Se esse for o caso, basta adicionar os respectivos caracteres dentro dos colchetes.
Por exemplo, `[!-,.:-@〝〞｢《]` incluiria todos os quatro caracteres de aspas já citados.

O mesmo vale para o hífen, pois também existem [vários caracteres diferentes que são chamados de hífen](http://www.fileformat.info/search/google.htm?q=hyphen&domains=www.fileformat.info&sitesearch=www.fileformat.info&client=pub-6975096118196151&forid=1&channel=1657057343&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&cof=GALT%3A%23008000%3BGL%3A1%3BDIV%3A%23336699%3BVLC%3A663399%3BAH%3Acenter%3BBGC%3AFFFFFF%3BLBGC%3A336699%3BALC%3A0000FF%3BLC%3A0000FF%3BT%3A000000%3BGFNT%3A0000FF%3BGIMP%3A0000FF%3BFORID%3A11&hl=en). Veja se não é o caso de incluí-los também.

---

#### Módulo `regex`

Se quiser, pode instalar o [módulo `regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), que possui suporte a alguns recursos que atualmente o módulo `re` não tem. Um deles é a possibilidade de usar propriedades do Unicode nas expressões, usando a sintaxe `\p`:

```
import regex

s = 'a"-b\':!?@#.c disse-lhe 〝〞｢《amá-la'
print('antes ', s)
s = regex.sub(r'[!-,.:-@\p{Ps}\p{Pe}]|(?<!\p{L})-|-(?!\p{L})', '', s)
print('depois', s)
```

A saída é:

```
antes  a"-b':!?@#.c disse-lhe 〝〞｢《amá-la
depois abc disse-lhe amá-la
```

As expressões `\p{Ps}` e `\p{Pe}` significam, respectivamente, qualquer caractere das categorias *Ps* (["Punctuation, Open"](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Ps/list.htm)) e *Pe* (["Punctuation, Close"](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pe/list.htm)), o que inclui todas as diferentes aspas que já citei.

Repare que também troquei as letras (`[a-z...]`) por `\p{L}`, que inclui qualquer letra definida pelo Unicode, tanto maiúscula quanto minúscula (por isso retirei a flag `IGNORECASE`). Esta opção talvez seja muito ampla porque inclui letras de outros alfabetos/idiomas (entre [neste link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm) e em seguida clique nas categorias que começam com "L" para ver todos os caracteres contemplados - só de letras minúsculas, por exemplo, [são mais de 2 mil](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Ll/list.htm)), então se quiser se limitar ao alfabeto latino, pode usar a expressão `[a-z...]`.

Infelizmente o `\p` ainda não é suportado pela API nativa de regex do Python, então a instalação deste módulo é uma boa alternativa para simplificar suas expressões. Mas fica a seu critério usar, tudo depende dos seus casos de uso (se não precisa incluir todos os caracteres de aspas e só vai trabalhar com o alfabeto latino, por exemplo, não precisa usar `\p`).